# Using sendTransaction in Web3.js

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm trying to make a function in my Dapps front end that requests Ether from the user, I know I have to use web3.eth.sendTransaction() but am unsure of how to correctly implement and call this function on the front end of my Dapp, thanks!

current code is:

```
   $("#button").click(function() {
    Raffle.main(function (err, result) {
      web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57 ,to:0x086912faa7f6598d28d80c448c8d1e9dae5a4dee, value:web3.toWei(1, "ether")});
      console.log(result);
      });
```

Comment: Please post your contract code.

Comment: @lunr to invoke the "send" function do I not just call it on an event in the front end?

Comment: Oh, I got it now. There are examples in the documentation: http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction (this is for web3.js 1.0 version)

Comment: @lunr yea, I'm already aware of that, I'm having trouble setting it up and calling in my contract

Comment: Please post what you have now, so someone can help. Your question is very broad now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this to work to call a function and send Ether with it, `to` is my contracts address, `value` is the amount in wei I want to send with it and `data` is the address of my function that I want to call when sending the data

```
  function mainEnter() {
        web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, result) {
        web3.eth.sendTransaction(
            {from:web3.eth.accounts[0],
            to:"0x943",
            value:  "1000000000000000000", 
            data: "0xdf"
                }, function(err, transactionHash) {
          if (!err)
            console.log(transactionHash + " success"); 
        });
    });

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Addresses should be strings:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: "0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57",
    to: "0x086912faa7f6598d28d80c448c8d1e9dae5a4dee", 
    value: web3.toWei(1, "ether"), 
}, function(err, transactionHash) {
    if (err) { 
        console.log(err); 
    } else {
        console.log(transactionHash);
    }
});
```

Comment: Even when in string format the function still doesn't call

Comment: How do you know it's not called?

Comment: when I can the function that the `sendTransaction` function is in the value on metamask doesn't go to 1 ETH

Comment: Please check the callback values.

Comment: `web3.utils.toWei(string, string)` https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-utils.html?highlight=toWei#towei